Weird movement using Mathf.LerpAngle Unity
I was making half 2d ,half 3d game. I wanted the up/down movement to be accompanied by a slight rotation in the direction the player is moving, for that I decided to use Mathf.LerpAngle method , because the documentetion says that the method

returns the shortest path between the specified angles

I also made a flip method which rotates(flips) player
void Flip()
   {
      facingRight =!facingRight;
      transform.Rotate(0,180,0);
   }
}

And Lerp
input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");


float angle = Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.rotation.x , input.y, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
transform.Rotate(angle, 0,0); 

When starting the game and after flipping the player while moving along the Y axis, LerpAngle causes a 360 degree rotation.
full code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
   public InputAction MoveAction;
   private Vector2 input;
   [SerializeField] float speed;
   [SerializeField] float rotateSpeed;
   private bool facingRight;
   private float inputH;


   // Start is called before the first frame update
   void Start()
   {
      MoveAction.Enable();  
   }


   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
    Vector2 move = MoveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    Vector2 position = (Vector2)transform.position + move * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    inputH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    

    float angle = Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.rotation.x , input.y, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
    transform.Rotate(angle, 0,0); 
   
    transform.position = position;
   }

   void FixedUpdate()
   {
      if(inputH > 0 && facingRight) Flip();
      else if(inputH < 0 && !facingRight) Flip();
   }
   
   void Flip()
   {
      facingRight =!facingRight;
      transform.Rotate(0 ,180,0);
   }
}

I tried:
Flip only the player's mesh, but this rotation still does not disappear at start.
I think because of the standard coordinates that are set by start and flip, Lerp Angle does not work as intended.

This looks really off to me: Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.rotation.x , input.y, ...  since input.y is in the range of -1 to 1, and rotation.x is a component of a Quaternion.
